# Send an alert about deployment failures to oncall engineer instead of person who person initiated deployment

Tags: azure-devops

Right now, If there is deployment failure, person who created deployment gets email notification. is there any way to get email alerts for oncall engineer or teammates as well?

OCE wants to get email about:

starting of deployment

deployment failures

Answer (score 0):

Ypu may use for that web hooks which you can integrate with third party apps or your custom functions:

[image]

and then you select action:

[image]

However, I don't know much about the way you handle on call schedule.

Another way would be create custom notification:

[image]